# Custom back button for Google Chrome

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-chrome

I've noticed in the latest iPhone Gmail app,  that if I tap a link (and if I have the Google Chrome iPhone app installed) it opens up Google Chrome, and changes the back button in Chrome to show it going back to "Gmail"

[image: google chrome back button]

I was wondering if anyone has managed to find a way to get this to work with their own apps, or if it's a private Google API?

I've tried Google's OpenInChromeController (https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/ios-links) though that only seems to provide helper methods to open Chrome, and not change the back button

Comment: Were you ever able to get this working? I've been trying to launch chrome with a back button, but I cannot see to figure it out.

Comment: Yeah definitely!  See @mergesort's answer below re: x-callback-urls, which has come to be the "standard" way iOS apps now talk with each other, as  no official way has been provided by Apple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome uses the x-callback-url scheme to create this type of behavior. 
One example is something like this:

```
googlechrome-x-callback://x-callback-url/open/?x-source=MyApp&x-success=com.myapp.callback%3A%2F%2F&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
```

You can customize it to have a different response for a success or failure, and define whether Chrome will open the link in a new tab. There's more information available lower in the document that you linked to.